# Apache2 howto serve different location for specific path in url

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I got a Virtualhost serving my application by ProxyPass and it works fine. now i want to serve an english version of my service using a simple Wordpress under '/en' route. assuming the Wordpress located in 'home/path/to/wp' how can i achieve this?
here's my current config under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ :

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>
ServerName xx.com
ServerAlias www.xx.com
SSLEngine on
.
.
.
ProxyPass /en !
<Directory home/path/to/wp>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
#DocumentRoot "home/path/to/wp"

AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php7.2 .php7.2
</Directory>
Redirect /en home/path/to/wp
ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3000/

#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^/en/(.*)$ /home/kerman/public_html [L,PT]
#Alias /en /home/kerman/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

as you see in the code I've tried `Redirect`, `Alias` and `Rewrite` but none of them works fine.

what is the practical workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You have tried everything, but nothing quite properly i.e. following the documentation.

First, your file system paths must be absolute paths starting from the root `/`. There's now many paths in your question, but to keep things simple let's just assume that your WordPress path is `/home/kerman/public_html/en` and everything else gets proxied to the backend `:3000`. ( #Comments are now used as comments.)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    # and here the keys & co.

    DocumentRoot /home/kerman/public_html

    # /en under the DocumentRoot i.e. /home/kerman/public_html/en
    # This must be before the ProxyPass for /
    ProxyPass /en !

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/

    <Directory /home/kerman/public_html>
        Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
        # All is All already: no need for a list
        AllowOverride All

        # Allow is deprecated, and this already does it
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

No need for workarounds.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I agree that the code was way too complicated. it was kind of a history of everything I tried :D, anyway one point you misunderstand is by `/en` i meant the path in the URL not the filesystem. _https://xx.com/en_ -> **WP** and all other urls from _backend:3000_  . this solution makes the `/en` url served by the **:3000** app

Comment: `ProxyPass /en !` removes the reverse proxy on that path and it falls back to the DocumentRoot relative content.

Comment: well, i pasted the same exact config and the **/en**  will serve from the backend instead of DocumentRoot

Comment: Change the order: `ProxyPass /en !` must be before `ProxyPass /` (first match).

Comment: not working :( I uploaded the new file to the gist, can you take a look at it? 
https://gist.github.com/mohandeath/da08ae46af1965cdab385be9f4e36d2a
i don't know what's wrong really

Comment: There's still so much unrelated & unnecessary stuff. Remove every line that isn't included in this configuration example and try again.